# RoR - `delete_at` like method in ActiveRecord::Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Maybe I'm just drowning in a glass of water...

I have two models.

> class Queue
>   has_many :slots
>   end
>
> class Slot
>   end

Execute this command in `rails c`

> q = Queue.create
>   s1 = Slot.create
>   s2 = Slot.create
>   s3 = Slot.create
>   q.slots << [ s1, s2, s3, s2, s3 ]

Now I want to delete ONLY the second element from q.slots list, without deleting others s2 elements (as #delete do). Something like `q.delete_at(1)`.
Any suggestions?

### Thanks.

### EDIT:

this is my schema.rb

> create_table "steps", force: true do |t|
>     t.integer value
>   end
>
> create_table "queues", force: true do |t|
>      t.string name
>    end
>
> create_table "steps_queues", force: true do |t|
>      t.integer "step_id"
>      t.integer "queue_id"
>    end
>
> add_index "steps_queues", ["step_id"], name: "index_steps_queues_on_step_id"
>    add_index "steps_queues", ["queue_id"], name: "index_steps_queues_on_queue_id"

### EDIT II:

I resolved this problem adopting the `has_many {:through}` association. Not very good idea adding an object model to achieve a non business logic purpose. But, hey, it'works.

Comment: Well for starters you have to save what you create in the console. So q.save s1.save ect...

Comment: Ok wrong example :D I tested with already created objects in my `rails console` session. But the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

a.delete_at(2) # a = [1,2,4,5,6]
```

The delete_at method will delete the index of the array you pass it.

If you want to remove an item based on its value you can use the delete method.

```
pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'parrot']

a.delete('dog')

# pets = ['cat', 'rabbit', 'parrot']
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In Rails AcriveRecord::Associations respond to #delete_at but it won't work (I think it acts on a clone of the array). While de #delete method will delete from the array all the references of the object.

Comment: Do you know what value in the array you want to delete?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord::Associations does not respond to #delete_at (it responds but nothing happens), but Array do it! So:

> arr = q.steps.to_a # return an Array
>    arr.delete_at(index_of_item_to_remove)
>    q.steps = [ ] # Eliminates all associations. This is a transaction with `q.steps.size` updates.
>    q.steps = arr # Insert associations of arr. This is a transaction with `arr.steps.size` updates.

Array#delete_at remove only the target item, while ActiveRecord::Associations#delete remove all equivalent items.

This approach is not the best, cause cost `(2 * (q.steps.size - 1)` number of updates. Could be implemented a custom SQL statement, this break astraction and it's a bad practice...sounds dirty. :@

*Still looking for a better solution*

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
q.slots[1].destroy # will destroy the second record, it will remain in the association cache though
q.slots(true)      # if you need the association again, passing true will refetch
```

You could also try:

```
q.slots.delete q.slots[1].destroy
```

This should remove the element from the cached association, without need for reload.

Comment: `q.slots[1].destroy` will remove the record from Slot table. I don't want this happens.

Comment: Hmmmm? Like you want Slot to still exist but the association to Queue broken? If so you'll need a join table. Unless I am completely misunderstanding your intent.

Comment: Infact the associations is mapped in a join table :) Yes I want Slot still exist but the association broken. #destroy and #delete methods wil remove Slot entity from DB.

Comment: Ok, I'll demonstrate; first can you add your schema to the original question?